precise reference
claim 1:
a method comprising;
storing the profiles of a plurality of users, each user having at least one picture;

claim 2:
a method comprising;
storing the profiles of a plurality of users, each user from the plurality of users having at least one picture;
Questions:

Any difference in meaning between the two claims?
Does "each user" in  claim 1 also reference potentially other users not from "the plurality of users"?


Storing a plurality of profiles, each such profile corresponding to a user, each such profile including at least one picture.
If you don't like "each such profile" it can be reworded to "each of said plurality of profiles".
Note that it is a common practice to store the pictures separately and just reference them from the profiles which this style of claim might not cover.

I meant to said, does "each user" in  claim 1 also reference potentially other users not from "the plurality of users"?
